# google cloud print tray media size

Tags: printing, google-cloud-print

I read the GCP documentation, I managed to grab in the google drive folder the documents I need to print every day before the guys enter the office, these docs are pdf in A5 format, I have the second tray filled with A5 paper.

By the GCP interface i can print all of them selecting A5 format (not the tray) and they are printed accordingly, using the script amended with the width and length size (148000 and 210000 in microns) I obtain the doc printed in **A5 format on the A4 paper**, I tried to change the tray paper but the printer got error ( Kyocera ).

I searched all the web looking for some info regarding how to set the tray, on the same GCP docs and also here in a question, I understand that I could grab printer capabilities by using `/printer` service, I think that in there I could read how to amend the ticket and selecting the tray if it would be possible. I do not understand how to use `/printer` service, any suggestion on how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can retrieve the printer's input trays by checking the `InputTrayUnit` attribute in the `PrinterDescriptionSection` of the [Cloud Device Description](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#pds), it is not possible to set this information in a job ticket: **There's no way to set the tray in the** `PrintTicketSection` **of the** [Cloud Job Ticket](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#cjt)

Comment: Thank you, that's understood. I do believe a Job Ticket including a media size A5 should be taken into account by the printer accordingly, and it is, but it is printed on a A4 sheet, while if I select A5 on google cloud printer option it does print on the right sheet by the tray number 2.

Comment: Printer would be smart enough to, once received the cloud job, decide which paper tray is better according to job media size and paper type set... This logic might be part of printer's firmware rather than cloud's.

Comment: Well, finally I have to set as default settings on the printer A5, before leaving the office, and I get all the papers printed the next morning. Did not fin any other way even contacting the printer maker.

Comment: Well, finally I have to set as default settings on the printer A5, before leaving the office, and I get all the papers printed the next morning. Did not fin any other way even contacting the printer maker.